# Handling crossproduct in R (vs. Python)

Tags: python, r, area

I ran onto an interesting difference in how things are handled in `R` and `Python` while trying to apply **shoelace formula** for the area. In `Python`, one can use `nympy` functionality straightforwardly:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = {"A": [2, 3, 1, 2], "B": [4, -8, 2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
area = 0.5 * np.abs(np.dot(df[df.columns[0]], np.roll(df[df.columns[1]], 1)) -
    np.dot(df[df.columns[1]], np.roll(df[df.columns[0]], 1)))
area
```

> 7.0

However, I failed to do the same in `R` with the `crossprod` (`%*%`) function, but only with quite basic iteration like this:

```
get_area <- function(x, y) {
    add.val <- sub.val <- NA
    for(i in 1:(length(x) - 1)) {
        add.val[i] <- 0.5 * x[i] * (y[i + 1])
        sub.val[i] <- 0.5 * y[i] * (x[i + 1])
    }
    return(abs(sum(add.val) - sum(sub.val)))
}
```

Is there something in `R` that is more efficient?

Answer (score 3):

It can be pretty stright forward in R if we just define some helper functions. For example

```
shift_left <- function(x)c(x[-1],x[1])
shift_right <- function(x)c(x[length(x)],x[-length(x)])

a <- c(2, 3, 1, 2)
b <- c(4, -8, 2, 4)
1/2 * abs(sum(a * (shift_left(b) - shift_right(b))))
# [1] 7
```